# On downvoting Comment should be compulsary?

Tags: support, feature-request, down-votes

Correct me if I am wrong,

Don't you guys think that there should be a provision by which user has to compulsory add the comment after down voting any post?

If this happens we can get help in identifying due to which mistake the post was down voted.

Please provide suggestion. Because I am sure this feature might have already thought by someone, and still is not implemented then it should have a proper reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, no I don't think so. A down vote in and of itself should trigger that something might be wrong with my answer. Review it to see if it matches with the intent of the question. Did I supply an answer that is all code when someone asks for no code solutions?

Was my answer too short or assumed some level of understanding that the user might not have?

If comments for down votes became a requirement, I think you'd just see a lack of down votes altogether. The sp.se forum is a little different than the other sites in the network. For the most part, people either upvote or don't vote at all.